# IoT management page with P2P connection

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot, portforwarding, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm really looking for advice and a starting point more than anything. So I'll try my best to explain my end goals and the challenge. I want to set up a local WiFi connection (P2P) between a Rpi3 (or any embedded system really, running linux) and a laptop. The Pi should be the server and laptop the client. The raspberry PI is going to be reading samples over USB from an SDR. I want the laptop to be able to connect to the network the pi throws up, and be able open a browser and view the results. I'm guessing what i need to read up on is ports/sockets and web programming in general. The cheepy IoT sensors and light bulbs seem to be able to do this (opening network and forwarding data) relatively easily but i cannot find any information online to aid in my quest. All the Best and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the embedded system will be running Linux, you can do something along the following lines:

1. setup the wifi as an Access Point ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)). Also setup DHCP Server ([example](https://www.tecmint.com/install-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu-debian/)), so the wifi will assign an IP address to connecting laptop.
2. Install a webserver (e.g. [Apache](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu/)).
3. Create the webpage/ web application you need to "serve" the data. Install this into Apache.

Ask follow-up questions if you like.

Comment: Hi John, is there any advantage to using an AP verses setting up a direct WIFI connection WIFI direct? I'm not sure the Raspberry pi supports AP mode. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: you are refering to ad-hoc mode (two nodes connect without an AP). This is only for special setups, and I highly discourage it since you need to setup both ends , every time. Setting up raspbery as an AP has nothing to do with the device, but with the OS. If it is linux, it does support it.

Comment: Got it to work thanks :) any benifit to apache over the flask?

Comment: Yes, one: Apache is so widespread, that no matter what problem you will have, you will find a solution to Mr. Google ;)